# PHP Mysql : Restaurant

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables storing rest_categories ,rest_type and rest_dish
cat_id is FK in rest_type & rest_dish also ty_id is FK in rest_dish.

When i try to display it using while loops it display only the first record

.
CODE :

```
            <?php
                $cat_ct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(cat_name) FROM rest_categories;");

                    $cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM   rest_categories");
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat)) 
                    {

                        $cat_id = $row["cat_id"];
                        $cat_name = $row["cat_name"];

            ?>


                        <h2><?php echo "$cat_name"; ?></h2>

                        <?php 
                        $ty_ct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ty_name) FROM rest_type;");

                            $cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rest_type where cat_id='$cat_id'");
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat)) 
                            {

                            $ty_id = $row["ty_id"];
                            $ty_name = $row["ty_name"];
                        ?>
                                <h3>  <?php echo "$ty_name"; ?> </h3>
                                <br>
                                <?php 
                                $dish_ct = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(dish_name) FROM rest_dish;");

                                    $cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rest_dish where cat_id='$cat_id' and ty_id='$ty_id'");
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($cat)) 
                                    {

                                    $dish_id = $row["dish_id"];
                                    $dish_price = $row["online_price"];
                                    $dish_name = $row["dish_name"];
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="wrapper pad_bot1">
                                        <table>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>
                                        <?php echo "$dish_name"; ?> </td>
                                        <td> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <?php echo "$dish_price"; ?> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </div>
                                        </table>



                                <?php } 
                        }               
                 } ?>


            </section>
        </div>
    </article>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$cat` was replaced in the inner loop. Just remove these conflicts.